# Write GeoTIFF File to GRIB2 Using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff, grib

I am looking to convert a GeoTIFF file to GRIB2, and define several pieces of metadata manually as seen in the provided literature [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/grib.html). I am using the GDAL library, specifically the script gdal translate.

My attempt to convert and pass specific metadata is as follows:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -mo DISCIPLINE=0 IDS_CENTER=248 IDS_SUBCENTER=4 IDS_MASTER_TABLE=24 IDS_SIGNF_REF_TIME=1 IDS_REF_TIME=2020-07-02T00:00:00Z IDS_PROD_STATUS=0 IDS_TYPE=1 PDS_PDTN=0 PDS_TEMPLATE_NUMBERS="0 4 2 0 96 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 103 0 0 0 0 2 255 0 0 0 0 0 7 228 7 2 13 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 1 255 0 0 0 0" PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES="0 4 2 0 96 0 0 1 0 103 0 2 255 0 0 2020 7 2 13 0 0 1 0 2 2 1 1 255 0" input.tif output.grb2
```

However, upon executing this command I receive the following error:

```
ERROR 6: Too many command options 'IDS_MASTER_TABLE=24'
```

Potential errors: Not calling the correct subprocess (currently using `-mo`) when attempting to pass the metadata, all metadata pairs must be encased in quotation marks, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an `-mo` flag for every metadata. Your command would become:

```sh
$ gdal_translate -b 1 \
    -mo DISCIPLINE=0 \
    -mo IDS_CENTER=248 \
    # etc.
    input.tif output.grb2
```

Comment: Thanks! Followed this approach and changed -mo to -co to get the desired result. The GRIB literature in GDAL is lengthy, and found this correction at the bottom. I will accept your answer!